# Eclipse stepping into class in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, dalvik

I have a simple android project that I am trying to debug inside of Eclipse.  When I run it in debug mode and use the "Step Over" button, it frequently seems to want to go into Android code (I don't want it to do this, just as a C debugger will not go into libc).  I get a screen that comes up which looks similar to:

```
Class File Editor

Source not found:

The JAR file blahblah/android.jar has no source attachment.
You can attach the source by clicking attach source
```

I don't want it to go into Android or Dalvik code at all
 (even if I could install source code) I am only interested in my own personal code.

Comment: I believe the answer, but it kind of sucks. In other development platforms (ie. .NET) skipping external code is set by default. I'm only concerned with my personal code.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I use mostly .NET at work, and now that I'm used to how easy this is in Visual Studio, I have to say that this is bullshit.  +1 for a good question.  Not sure why Eclipse can't make debugging easy; there's very few cases where you actually want to step into framework code.

Comment: I also don't want to step into android's code. Anyone find a better solution then the one proposed by apesa for creating multiple breakpoints and clicking resume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you "step" you may be run through some platform/SDK code while moving between Activities even if your code seems to be running clean. To work around this I set a breakpoint somewhere within the next Activity and step through the current Activity and then once I hit the end of the code I hit resume and it breaks in my next Activity skipping any code that is not mine. Not the most elegant, but it works for me.

In Debug you will always be run through the exception handling platform..

Answer (score 7):

not sure if it works for Android, but for Java SE you can set Step Filtering in the preferences to avoid stepping into some package/class:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering
```

Mark "Use Step Filters", add the packages and classes to ignore, mark "Step through filters".

[image]

Eventually you need to turn off the "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions" to avoid the debugger stopping in case of an exception:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as you have to filter other classes so that you can only see your code during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse:

> F5 = go into; F6 = jump over; F7 = go upwards: F8 = go to next
>   breackpoint or exit

I always use it like this and never had a problem. :)